# Accessing template attributes in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am declaring a variable in `Chef/Ruby` and assigning it a value. The value is different for different environments. I am setting the value in respective environment files like this:

```
region = us-west-1
```

In the template file I am using it this way

```
region =<%= @region %>
```

and in the recipe as

```
:region =>node.region
```

The instance doesn't come up when my fix is merged.
Is this right way of doing it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two of my favourite ways to do that:

- Use chef attributes.

Define the default for the attribute in an attribute file. so in `<cookbook_name>/attributes/default.rb` file add this line:

```
default['instance_region'] = 'us-west-1'
```

and then in your recipe where you are adding the template:

```
variables(region: node['instance_region'])
```

you can access that in you template as you mentioned:

```
region =<%= @region %>
```

- Using chef library.

For wider usage you can define such value within a chef library. so in `<cookbook>/libraries/common.rb` add:

```
module Common
   def instance_region
     # This will return the name of AWS region that the nodes is in.
     shell_out!('curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/').stdout
   end
 end
```

and then in your recipe you can use it just by calling plain `instance_region`

Comment: thank you for your response. the value is different for various environments. it's one region for all accounts except one. how can i deal with such situation in the attribute file?

Comment: then i think the second option works best for you. As it will automatically get to know the region that your instance is in, and put that value in the variable.
in any AWS executing this:  `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/` will give you back the instance region that its in.

Comment: @spinnp please upvote the answer if you find it helpful

Comment: i tried to upvote but couldn't as i only have 13 reputations. Also, :region =>node.region --- this style is depricated and deleted in chef13, i ran into an error but fixed it following this :https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_attributes.html